# findElements by multiple different xpaths

Tags: java, selenium, xpath

I have this bit of code, I am not sure why it is not working.

```
String xpath1="//span[contains(text(),'I am span')]";
String xpath2="//div[contains(text(),'I am Div')]";
String xpath3="//input[contains(text(),'I am input')]";
```

then I combnie all the xpaths like this.

```
String majorxpath="\""+xpath1+" or "+xpath2+" or "+xpath3+"\"";
List<Webelemnt> results=driver.findelements(By.xpath(majorxpath));
```

This returns error, unable to locate an elemnent by majorxpath.

Please note that, I want to evaluate x`path1, xpath2, xpath 3` together and if any of them exists, the webelemnt should return in `results`

Also, note the xpaths work individually but I want to see if any of them are existing and return the webElemnt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below `xpath` to identify.

```
//span[contains(text(),'I am span')] | //div[contains(text(),'I am Div')] | //input[contains(text(),'I am input')]
```

Comment: this works, i wonder why the "or" ` "\""+xpath1+" | "+xpath2+" | "+xpath3+"\"";` dont work.

Comment: @BountyCollector - "or" is allowed in a predicate expression, but not in a location path. "|" works because it is the union operator which is much different than "or". See https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-10/#node-sets for more info.